# How to find if SQS queue was created manually or using CF template?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

I've tried the following, but it's not giving me any CF Template ID or any description that allows me to find.

**Example:**

```
aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyQueue --attribute-names All*
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Attributes": {
    "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible": "0",
    "RedrivePolicy": "{\"deadLetterTargetArn\":\"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:80398EXAMPLE:MyDeadLetterQueue\",\"maxReceiveCount\":1000}",
    "MessageRetentionPeriod": "345600",
    "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesDelayed": "0",

 "MaximumMessageSize": "262144",
    "CreatedTimestamp": "1442426968",
    "ApproximateNumberOfMessages": "0",
    "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds": "0",
    "DelaySeconds": "0",
    "VisibilityTimeout": "30",
    "LastModifiedTimestamp": "1442426968",
    "QueueArn": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:80398EXAMPLE:MyNewQueue"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to determine whether an SQS queue is part of a CloudFormation stack by passing the Queue URL (which is the [Physical ID of an `AWS::SQS::Queue` Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sqs-queues.html#aws-properties-sqs-queues-ref)) as the [**`PhysicalResourceId`**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html#API_DescribeStackResources_RequestParameters) parameter to [`DescribeStackResources`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStackResources.html).

Using the AWS CLI [`describe-stack-resources`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stack-resources.html) command, you will need to pass the parameter using `--cli-input-json [json_file]`, because the `--physical-resource-id` parameter will try to resolve the Queue URL when provided directly.

Example:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --cli-input-json '{"PhysicalResourceId": "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/80398EXAMPLE/MyQueue"}'
```

If the queue is part of a stack, then a list of the stack's resources will be returned. If not, then a `ValidationError` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Few little additions to @wjordan's answer (which was super helpful, thanks!)

1. For me, this syntax was the one to use:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stack-resources --cli-input-json "{\"PhysicalResourceId\": \"<sqs_queue_url>\"}"
```

(syntax in original answer resulted in an error "Unknown options: <sqs_queue_url>")

2. User must specify AWS region first in order to be able to use that command
3. I faced several error/validation messages when trying this command but I believe the one that means that this SQS queue doesn't belong to a stack should be this one:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DescribeStackResources operation: Stack for <sqs_queue_url> does not exist
```

Comment: Your answer does not contain an alternative or improved answer over the already accepted answer.

Comment: My opinion is that it does:
1. Provides the correct command for me (so I'm guessing I'm not alone needing it)
2. Provides pre-requisite step in order to run accepted answer's command
3. Provides the validation error message to expect when everything works fine

What's the added value of your comment though?

Comment: While my comment may seem harsh it was one of the preset review responses available to moderators.